# « É » et « è » dans l'orthographe historique

Tags: orthographe, histoire, typographie

Dans le livre « Traité d'Harmonie » de Catel, je rencontre quelques graphies qui me paraissent irrégulières :

[image: La gamme renferme les intervalles de seconde, tierce, quarte, quinte, sixte, septiéme et octave. En doublant les intervalles on trouve ceux de neuviéme, dixiéme, onziéme, douziéme, treiziéme, quatorziéme, et quinziéme, qui sont la répétition des premiers, à l'octave au dessus.]

C'est la [version numérisée](https://imslp.org/wiki/Trait%C3%A9_d%E2%80%99harmonie_(Catel%2C_Charles-Simon)) disponible sur l'IMSLP. Il y a des points où la qualité de l'image n'est pas parfaite, mais ces exemples (qui montrent que les adjectifs ordinaux sont imprimés avec é au lieu de è) sont plus ou moins récurrents partout dans l'œuvre.

Cette édition du livre fut imprimée et le contenu fut écrit durant [les premières années de la République](https://archive.org/details/traitdharmonie00cate/page/n2) (au tournant du XVIII<sup>e</sup> siècle). Est-ce que cette orthographe était commune durant cette époque ?  Ces mots étaient-ils prononcés avec /e/ et pas avec /ɛ/ ?

Ce livre contient d'autres exemples d'orthographes vieillies, mais celle des nombres n'est pas attestée dans ma recherche (Littré, Wiktionnaire, requêtes générales sur Google).

Answer (score 1):

L'accentuation de certains mots de cet ouvrage ne respecte pas les standards modernes mais reste cohérente. Elle correspond à des archaïsmes dont voici un exemple.

*Le Theatre de Corneille, reveu et corrigé par l'Autheur*, 1663 :

[image]

Voici d'autres exemples trouvés dans le « Traité d'Harmonie » de Catel:

> toute enti**e**re
>
> V**û** l'adoption
>
> la mani**e**re
>
> au même d**é**gré

Une seule accentuation semble fautive, même pour l'époque:

> o**ù** de la double octave.

Answer (score 0):

*"N'avons rien innové par curiosité mais avons fait ce qui t'est utile et en soulagement"*

On notera donc qu'à l'origine, l'accent relève plus de la typographie que de l'orthographe.

L'accent aigu commence à se répandre vers la mi-XVIe.
D'abord dans le *Nouveau Testament* pour indiquer la prononciation de certains noms propres avec voyelle en hiatus. (par ex Canan**é**en)

Il apparaît sur les ordinaux très peu de temps après.
Meigret (*Tretté de la grammère françoeze* (mi-XVIe)) consigne ce cas des ordinaux qui correspond au schéma e + consonne + e-muet.

La prononciation (timbre et longueur) varie beaucoup. Ainsi, pour Meigret, le é de la finale des ordinaux correspond à un e fermé bref alors que pour Peletier (même époque), "*les ordinaux sont parmi les rares mots de ce type à présenter un e fermé long*"